# React Native performance for UI libraries. Which should I use : Native base vs React-Native paper?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base, react-native-paper

I am developing an android app using React-Native. I bumped into two UI libraries: React-Native paper and Native-base.
I have noticed that my app is slow when I am debugging and I am worried about which of these two libraries has a better performance.

Please assist/recommend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends upon UI requirements in your app. Native base is a large library and has lots of stable cross-platform features hence its build size is also large.

You can compare build size of both UI libraries here https://bundlephobia.com
I have compared and got the following results:
for Native base 
[view native base build size](https://bundlephobia.com/scan-results?packages=blueimp-md5@2.5.0,clamp@1.0.1,color@1.0.3,fs-extra@2.0.0,jest-react-native@18.0.0,lodash@4.17.11,native-base-shoutem-theme@0.2.3,print-message@2.1.0,prop-types@15.5.10,react-native-drawer@2.5.1,react-native-easy-grid@0.2.1,react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view@0.8.0,react-native-vector-icons@6.1.0,react-tween-state@0.1.5,tween-functions@1.0.1,react-timer-mixin@0.13.4)

for RN paper
[view RN paper build size](https://bundlephobia.com/scan-results?packages=@callstack/react-theme-provider@1.0.7,color@2.0.1,create-react-context@0.2.3,hoist-non-react-statics@3.1.0,react-lifecycles-compat@3.0.4)

Answer (score 1):

with thanks to `Ankit Dubey` for his way to compare bundle size, you can also use [npmtrends](https://www.npmtrends.com/) for checking and comparing packages via great information about the packages. (you can also change comparison time, eg 6 months, 1 year, 5 years, all time, and so on)

Here, I compare three major react-native UI library, **native-base**, **react-native-elements** and **react-native-paper**:  [view RN UI library Comparistion](https://www.npmtrends.com/native-base-vs-react-native-elements-vs-react-native-paper)